# AlertDialog how to close Keyboard after inputs

Tags: android, crash, keyboard, hide, android-alertdialog

Can´t get the MainScreen Activity to run. Always get a `NullPointerException` at the `add.setOnClickListener`

In your solution, the `onClickListener` looks different, couldn´t figure out what you mean.

```
final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_name);
        final Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainScreen.this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.name_prompt);
        dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        dialog.show();

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("Clicked");
                dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
            }
        });
```

---

This is my best solution so far. Only problem is, that the keyboard won´t disappear automatically after input is done. Only pressing the return button will close the keyboard.

```
           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        final EditText input = new EditText(getBaseContext());

        input.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        input.setHint(R.string.hint_name);
        input.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10)});
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        input.setMaxLines(1);
        input.setFocusable(true);

        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setView(input);

        builder.setPositiveButton("ADD", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                if (input.getText().length() == 0)
                    players.add(new Player(0, "Nobody"));
                else
                    players.add(new Player(0, input.getText().toString()));
            }
        });
        builder.show();
        input.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok just to give you an idea.

**Edit:**
New answer problem 1:

```
alert.setNegativeButton(cancel,
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            saveimage();
            InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(input.getWindowToken(), 0);
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
```

Answer problem 2:

```
builder.setCancelable(false);
```

This should get you going.

Comment: thx, so you are saying i should create my own Dialog instead of using AlertDialog. Will try tomorrow

Comment: Exactly. You have more controle then.

Comment: Unfortunatly i couldn´t get it to work. Edited first post. 
Problem 2 was solved. thx